# USB-keyboard & mouse powered off in windows-7

Tags: windows-7, usb, truecrypt, sysinternals

I have a problem with a pc where usb devices are not getting any power as soon as windows starts up (it works in preboot). This pc has no ps/2, so there is no chance for input, also not in secure boot mode. I "tidied up" using sysinternals autostart, so there is a chance I messed something up here, although I'm quite sure I only deleted some old printer drivers from autostart.

I do not know how to reset this, I cant even log in because there is no input possible. I could use a linux live cd, but I don't know what to do there because there is no sysinternals from linux into a not running windows...

To make things even worse, I have the windows installation completely encrypted with truecrypt, so I haven't even tried windows recovery cd yet.

There is no loss of data since I can access the disc with a live-linux, I only want to use it again without resetting up everything.

Any suggestions?

//Ok, great thanks to Peter Maxwell. After acessing the pc via remote desktop I could use autoruns from sysinternals to reset the settings to an earlier state which solved the problem. Although, I keep wondering why disabling some printer drivers from brother has such a drastic effect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unplug the mouse and keyboard, boot windows. Once it gets to the login screen plug the mouse and keyboard back in and it should work.

Comment: i tried plugging in another usb mouse when windows showed the login screen. that didn't work. i suppose it also wouldn't work with the mouse already attached.

Comment: Are you running windows 7 pro by any chance?

Comment: yes i'm running win 7 pro x64. usb is completely powered off. if i plug in a usb keydrive with an led that usually blinks, it stays dark.

Comment: Do you have remote desktop enabled?

Comment: Great! You are very welcome. I hope that works for you.

Comment: Works. So I just need to know what I need to fix now, the "how" is solved.

Comment: Right, now just undo what you did before. Or reinstall the drivers.